# Am I allowed to ask a question here about 'interpolation value'?

Tags: discussion

I asked on StackExchange for where can I ask a question about interpolation value on a TV that I want to buy, and an answer pointed me to this site.

My question (with all the details) is this:

> I want to buy this Medion TV that I looked up online. There are no
>   shops where I can check it live, so I compared it to a Sony TV that I
>   saw and really liked at an electronic shop in my city, using this
>   website: https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/comparison/9bfead8b9
>
> At the frame interpolation section the Medion shows an interpolation
>   value of 1200, whereas Sony shows 800. Sony shows a vertical
>   frequency(digital) of 120Hz, and Medion shows 60Hz. So now I am a bit
>   confused. Googling interpolation value shows that it's proportional to
>   frequency. So I don't understand why Medion has a higher interpolation value than
>   Sony, when Medion's frequency is lower.
>
> What does interpolation value actually mean?

Is this question okay to ask for this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this would not be a production question.  Frame interpolation by a TV isn't really related at all to video production.

This is, unfortunately a purely consumption side thing and is probably marketing gibberish.  "Interpolation Value" doesn't even really make any sense since interpolation is just creation of in-between frames when dealing with a lower frame rate source.  Interpolation is something that is done in video production, but "interpolation value" is nonsensical and the automatic interpolation done by a TV, while similar in technique, is not really on topic when dealing specifically with TVs.

Comment: I'm sure there some vague calculation they do to come up with this "interpolation value."  What that's supposed to mean is really the question. I agree on the off topic nature of it though

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure they have some kind of method but I can't imagine it means much.